# How to customized the column width in datagridview in .NET Windows form

Tags: .net, datagridview

I have a datagridview, whenever I click or double click a row, I need to know which ID the row has and the ID will need to be passed to another function to populate other controls.

Can anyone tell me what event(s) should I use?

I don't need to consider multiple selections here.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set the `.DataSource` to provide your data, you will need a bit of code to retrieve the underlying `DataRow`. This is because if you sort the DataGridView by clicking on a column heading, you can no longer rely on the `.RowIndex` to match those in the underlying DataSource.

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            var x = ((DataRowView)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Row.Field<string>("Id");
            MessageBox.Show(x);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you SSS, that is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Glad it was helpful, happy programming!